# Plot a series from a variable containing a vector in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

First off: there does already exist another question with nearly the same title [Plot a list of lines with R lattice package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826470/plot-a-list-of-lines-with-r-lattice-package) : but the intent on that one is different - that one wants a separate plot for each column. My need is a single plot with a series containing each of the lines superimposed. For that purpose a working hard-coded column names version is:

```
library(lattice)
library(tibble)
cols = c('confirmed','recovered','exposed')

df = tibble( exposed= c(50,80,90), confirmed= c(10,20,30), recovered= c(3,5,7))
City1=df
Day = c(1:length(df))

Exposed=df$exposed
Confirmed=df$confirmed
Recovered=df$recovered
xyplot(Exposed + Confirmed + Recovered~ Day, main='City1 Stats',xlab='Day',ylab='Cases', 
cex.lab=0.6, xaxt="n", type = "l", auto.key = list(points = FALSE,lines = TRUE, 
  par.settings  = list(superpose.line = list(col = c("green","red","orange")))))
```

[image]

I would prefer to send in a vector of column names instead of hardcoded: how to do that? The form of it would be something like:

```
plotVars = c(Exposed, Confirmed, Recovered)
xyplot( plotVars ~ Day, main='City1 Stats',xlab='Day',ylab='Cases', 
  cex.lab=0.6, xaxt="n", type = "l", 
  auto.key = list(points = FALSE,lines = TRUE, 
  par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = c("green","red","orange")))))
```

What should be done to make `plotVars` a comprehensible list for `xyplot` ?

**Update** From an answer below the recommendation is to use `paste` to set the column names with `+` as a separator. Here is the updated code using that approach:

```
library(lattice)
cols = c('confirmed','recovered','exposed')

df = tibble( exposed= c(50,80,90), confirmed= c(10,20,30), recovered= c(3,5,7))
City1=df
Day = c(1:length(df))

exposed=df$exposed
confirmed=df$confirmed
recovered=df$recovered
fml = formula(paste(paste0(cols, collapse = " + "), "Day", sep = " ~ "))

xyplot(fml, main='City1 Stats',xlab='Day',ylab='Cases', cex.lab=0.6,
 xaxt="n", type = "l", auto.key = list(points = FALSE,lines = TRUE, 
 par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = c("green","red","orange")))))
```

Comment: Would you be ok with specifying a character vector of vars and then paste them in xyplot for creating a formula object? If so I could create a more detailed answer.

Comment: @agila  Yes : even if it seems a bit involved the logic could be buried in a function written once and  providing the functionality needed. pls do put up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mean with the previous comment. Probably there are better ways to specify the formula of the plot, but I cannot think of anything better at the moment.

```r
# packages
library(lattice)
library(tibble)

# data
df = tibble(
  exposed = c(50, 80, 90), 
  confirmed = c(10, 20, 30),
  recovered= c(3, 5, 7)
)
Day = seq_len(nrow(df))

# plot
plotVars = c("exposed", "confirmed", "recovered")

xyplot(
  formula(paste(paste0(plotVars, collapse = " + "), "Day", sep = " ~ ")), 
  data = df,
  main = 'City1 Stats',
  xlab = 'Day',
  ylab = 'Cases',
  cex.lab = 0.6,
  xaxt = "n",
  type = "l", 
  auto.key = list(
    points = FALSE, 
    lines = TRUE, 
    par.settings  = list(
      superpose.line = list(col = c("green","red","orange"))
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The core of your answer i'd say is this `formula(paste(paste0(plotVars, collapse = " + "), "Day", sep = " ~ "))` . And yes that was what I was looking for.

Comment: i'm getting this: `Exception: formal argument "collapse" matched by multiple actual arguments`

Comment: Can you please add a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) of the error to the original question?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: @javadba I'm sorry but I cannot reproduce your error. If I run your code on my laptop I get the following error: "Error in eval(i, data, env): object 'confirmed' not found" and if I simply change `c('confirmed', 'recovered' ,'exposed')` into `c('Confirmed', 'Recovered', 'Exposed')` then everything works fine. Could you try running the same code in a clean R environment?

Comment: OK yea i had to change casing as you say. Its working now